# Audio channel selection in Java JMF

Tags: java, audio, jmf

I am using Java JMF to play a MPEG video with sound. I want to select the left audio channel when playing. How to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that we could not select the left or right audio channel in JMF.